# My call application stops running, I don't have any code errors

Tags: android

My application just stops running and I don't understand why; I think my code is correct. It's just a simple CALL application

```
Button b; 
Context= mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:0102030405"));
                startActivity(call);


                return;
            }

        }

        }

    );
}
```

Comment: check the logs in android moniter

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: i changed Context= mContext; to    Context mCotenxt, but still doesn't work

Comment: Also did you add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` to manifest

Comment: Yes i did put the permission

Comment: The logs are normal.

Comment: Are you testing on Android 6.0+?

Comment: `The logs are normal.` How enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

initialize context as mContext = getApplicationContext(); inside onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the activity if the permission is not granted which is wrong. Write the code to be executed once you have permission, in the else part. Also pass this as the context.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);


    }
} else {
 Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:0102030405"));
                startActivity(call);

}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:0102030405"));
                startActivity(call);
            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Also, add the following line to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private EditText ed_call;
        private Button btn_call;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ed_call = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_call);
            btn_call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call);

            btn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ed_call.getText().toString()));
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            return;
                        }
                        startActivity(callintent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.actiondemo.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_call"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_call"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

May this helps you.